# Return inserted values from 'insert' query

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, sql-insert, unique-constraint

I have simple table and I need to insert in to it values from array, but only values which are not exists in table and return from query inserted values, how I can do this?
I have next query, but it just inserts values:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(id, card_id, size) 
    VALUES ${myArray.map(item => `($${addDbValue(item.id, dbValues)}, 
    $${dbValues.push(item.card_id)}::int, '24')`)}
     `, dbValues)
```

unique is `card_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want `on conflict` and `returning`:

```
insert into my_table(id, card_id, size) 
values (?, ?, ?)
on conflict (card_id) do nothing
returning *
```

The query inserts the new row, and returns the entire row (including columns that were not initially given for insert). If a row already exists with the same `card_id`, the insert is not performed (for this to work, you need a unique index or constraint on `card_id`).

Note that you should be using query parameters (as shown above) rather than concatenating variables in the query string. Have a look at the parameterized query feature of your client.